# Filter data vector - get rid of noise - retain peaks (max and min)

Tags: filtering

I have a distance sensor (acoustic) that has temperature-dependent noise signal. I want to retain the peaks, but get rid of the temperature related noise.

I need a program that checks the absolute value of the difference between the current and previous measurement (e.g. abs(d1[i+1]-d1[i])). If the difference is less than or equal to a threshold (delta), then d2[i+1] = d1[i]. If the difference is greater than delta, then d2[i+1]=d1[i+1]. An example vector looks something like:
data vector d1 is 4,6,5,7,6,5,7,10,55,56,58,30,10
The desired, filtered data (d2) would look something like (in this case delta=1): 4,6,6,7,7,7,7,10,55,55,58,30,10

I looked at lowess() and sma(), but they were unsatisfactory, or my ability to apply them correctly is unsatisfactory.  I have used lowess in previous attempts, but it was inconsistent in capturing peaks and valleys. It seems a combination of sapply() and an ifelse() function should be able to do this, but my skill level is too poor.  Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: it's not possible. Noise is also present in the peaks, and contribute to make it a peak.

Comment: I must have asked my question poorly as I do not understand your answer.  If you carefully measure the surface of a hairy dog, you will have a noisy surface. You should be able to filter the data and retain the shape of the dog. If you sample forested terrain with LiDar you will get a complex surface, but filtering the data will give you the underlying shape of the topography.  I am trying to get the real changes in distance, filtered from temperature-related noise generated by my instrument. I believe this is a simple problem that has been solved many time before.

Comment: That's not simple at all. There's a whole field of research behind of it called "estimation theory". Basically you need to model observed measurement as true data plus noise, and then further model model data and noise. E.g. your dog's true shape needs to have a head and 4 legs so your noise removal operation does not smooth it into a cylinder. The noise is modeled as zero-mean so the the mean of the fur outlines the shape of the dog. Other models include CV, constant velocity, is used for filtering location tracking data for object won't change speed abruptly.

Comment: Simplest is the classic "band-limited" model, which basically says your data should be smooth and anything changes abruptly must be noise, then the noise removal method is to low-pass filter the data.

Comment: Thank you user3528438.  You have confirmed my question in terminology that is more appropriate. I understand the concept, but what I really need is help writing a few lines of R that will run a low -pass filter on my data vector. It would be most helpful if I could experiment with the threshold (what I called delta) in my example above.  Could you please give me some help with a few lines of R code? I suspect sapply with an ifelse condition?  Thank you!

Comment: I googled "low pass filter R" and a very useful thread came up on stackoverflow.  It turns out that loess does exactly what I want.  I was beating on lowess and it was lot producing.  I am a dinosaur and remembered lowess from S three decades ago.  Once user3528438 gave me the proper term to search, I quickly found the solution.  Thank you.